# On group theory terminology

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology

Let $G$ be a finite group. Consider the next number

$$m(G):=\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid G\ \text{can be embedded into}\ S_{m}\}.$$

It is obvious that Cayley's theorem yields $m(G)\leq |G|$.

My question:

> Does $m(G)$ have a common name in group theory?

Comment: Do you mean $m(G) \leq |G|$?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for correction!

Answer (score 5):

In this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1668v1.pdf they call it  the 'Minimal degree for a permutation representation'