# Finding the smallest set on which a group acts faithfully

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, computational-complexity, permutations

Given a finite group $G$, how efficient can one make an algorithm to find the size of the **smallest** set $S$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations of the members of $S$?  And does the answer change if one requires the output to specify not only the cardinality of $S$ but the particular action of $G$ on $S$?  Might this be an NP-hard problem?  Or is it a trivial thing whose solution is known to everyone on earth except me?  Or somewhere in between?

Comment: What's trivial are the bounds that $\#G$ divides $\#S!$ and $\#S\le \#G$ or that the answer for cyclic $G$ of order $\prod p^{k_p}$ is $\sum p^{k_p}$, bu tbeyond that things can get messy ...

Comment: I think this is a difficult problem, and that there is no efficient algorithm known. It might be easier to find an action that was close to being optimal.

Comment: Slightly less trivial is that $|S|<|G|$ except when $G$ is prime cyclic or generalized quaternion.  I do remember a question about this very thing being asked on math.SE a while ago, and @JackSchmidt giving a nice summary of what's known.  But I cannot find it now.

Comment: Here are Jack Schmidt's answers, apparently mostly on group theory: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/583/jack-schmidt?tab=answers

Comment: Haha, I don't know that I would consider a Friday night spent combing through math.SE answers a worthwhile venture. :)

Comment: Also see this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514650/on-group-theory-terminology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/16863/22971) for links to several important papers.

The main citation is: Johnson, D. L. "Minimal permutation representations of finite groups." Amer. J. Math. 93 (1971), 857-866.

**Edit (10/30/13):** Check the comment below for an entire book on this subject.

Comment: I now find what appears to be a whole book addressing this question: Neil Saunders, _Minimal Faithful Permutation Representations of Finite Groups_, University of Sydney, 2011 http://books.google.com/books?id=JGoiuAAACAAJ&dq=%22Minimal+Faithful+Permutation+Representations+of+Finite+Groups%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rJZxUsajG6PhygGF5IGABg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA PS: OK, I now see that it's a Ph.D. thesis.  It turned up in a Google Books search.